# How to track gmail logged In user's email from google analytics report via analytic code snippet?

Tags: google-analytics, gmail, web-analytics

Is it possible to track which gmail user visit my website with the help of google analytics code script.

Please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should closely read   [Google Analytics Terms of Service](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7124332?hl=en)

> 7. Privacy.
>     You will not and will not assist or permit any third party to, pass information to Google that Google could use or
>      recognize as personally identifiable information.

and [Universal Analytics usage guidelines](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en)

> Analytics customers are **prohibited** from sending personal information
>   to Google. The Analytics terms of service, which all Analytics
>   customers must adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable
>   information (PII) to Analytics (such as names, social security
>   numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that
>   permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s
>   unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset). Learn
>   more about how to avoid sending PII. Your Analytics account could be
>   terminated and your data destroyed if you use any of this information.

also this [Best practices to avoid sending Personally Identifiable Information (PII)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en)

> Analytics features and privacy risk
>
> Special care should be taken to ensure no PII such as names, social
>   security numbers, email addresses, or any similar personal
>   identifiers, or data that permanently identifies a particular device
>   such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier

**Answer:**  It is against Google Analytics TOS to store any information that could be used to track back to a specific users.   This would include the gmail user id or email.

Comment: Thanks Dalm To, I was thinking to tag with user's email who have already logged In via email. Is there any other work around so I can harvest email ?

Comment: No It clearly states that there may not be any information in your Google Analytics account that can be used to identify a user in any way shape or form.  Especially email even if you send email as a custom dimension Google will just over write it.   Google Analytics is not for tracking people its for tracking NON-user specific website activity.